# Issues in the navigation of a slideshow

Tags: css

I have a slideshow ([you can find the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/jofb4o4s/4/)) with the navigation in blue and the active slide with a border. But I want to highlight the active slide box with another color.

I tried this :

```
#cycle-nav ul li a:activeSlide {
    background: #075262;
}
```

It is not working. I tried to add opacity but it gets applied to all boxes.
How can I do that?

Comment: I believe that it's not a php question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight the background of the active slide, you want

```css
#cycle-nav ul li.activeSlide > a {
    background: #075262;
}
```

To highlight the background of the active slide and apply a different opacity ([demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jofb4o4s/5/show/)), you want

```css
#cycle-nav ul li > a {
    opacity: 0.3;
}   
#cycle-nav ul li.activeSlide > a {
    background: #075262;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

To answer 2), I'd probably need to see some example code. I'll update this when I can. You might want to look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) - [this introduction](http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html) is quite good.

Comment: @ enigma: hey thanks. its working fine with above code. Can you please tell me, if I want to apply opacity to boxes other than active slide, how can i do that? As its getting applied to all boxes when i tried. And for 2) , I am trying to fix the width of navigation div so that it will be responsive for all sizes. With the media queries i have to write css for all sizes which i am not preferring. So finding solution of having one css (e.g width in %)  for navigation div.

Comment: @kiran I've updated my answer for the opacity. I'm not really sure what you want for the navigation div, but you can try something like `#cycle-nav {
    width: 10%;
}` - this causes the little squares to wrap onto two lines, on my screen size at least

Comment: @ enigma: thanks a lot for the help. It looks as I was expecting.